# How to verify the genuine user identity using Google signin API?

Tags: tls, authentication, account-security, sso

I'm developing a mobile app. I have a question, and here is the scenario.

If a person is logging into the App with google sign in API in a public network. The website will verify the user with his `Email ID` and if verified the website will in return returns the user details like his mobile number, address, and somethings. Meanwhile, from that Public network, a person has sniffed the `Email ID` of the user and that person uses that `Email ID` to retrieve the user details.

In this case, how can I verify the genuine user?

- Is there is some other technique to overcome this thing?
- Should I use TLS to overcome this vulnerability?

Comment: You should generally always use TLS everywhere.

Comment: Why are you not using TLS to pass authentication details??